# Live rebuild of client side code in JHipster while developing remotely

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I'm somewhat new to JHipster and have used grunt in the past to live reload changes to client side code in Tomcat webapps. I'm wondering what best practices are to do the same with JHipster. The documentation discusses using "yarn start" or "npm start" when working on your local machine. I need to work remotely on an AWS box and can't do Browsersync.

As I make changes in the /src tree I'd like them to get picked up and deployed into the /target tree so I'll see them with a browser refresh.

Curious what other have done in this situation and would appreciate any recommendations on how to accelerate JHipster client side development on a remote server.

Thanks!